# iOS UIAccessibilityReadingContent protocol on (Mac Designed app / Catalyst)

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst, catalyst

I am trying to struggle with the adoption of the iOS application to OS X. We have decided to go with iPad designed application that runs on Mac. Meanwhile, a lot of issues are fixed there is one issue with accessibility which looks like Apple's bug (but I do not affirm this).

MacOS either (Catalyst or iPad designed) does not get calling methods from UIAccessibilityReadingContent protocol. As iOS application is working well with UIAccessibilityReadingContent protocol and calling all of them. In their documentation Apple says it should be supported by Catalyst.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityreadingcontent

Have any of you guys had the same issue? What is the way to solve it (by using rotors, etc. from the protocol)

Thanks for your answers

```
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
func accessibilityLineNumber(for point: CGPoint) -> Int

@available(iOS 5.0, *)
func accessibilityContent(forLineNumber lineNumber: Int) -> String?

@available(iOS 5.0, *)
func accessibilityFrame(forLineNumber lineNumber: Int) -> CGRect

@available(iOS 5.0, *)
func accessibilityPageContent() -> String?
```